# how can i use the recorded Objects button in JProfiler

Tags: jprofiler

As a JProfiler beginner, I encountered an error while testing my program. When I clicked on the button in the "recorded objects" view of the Telemetries tab, the program threw an exception: "java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"". This caused the connection between JProfiler and IDEA to break, and JProfiler displayed an "overhead warning". Why is this error occurring, and what steps can I take to use this feature properly?
my program is：

```
public class MemoryAnalyse {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int pid = 0;
        while(pid < 1000000){
            Person person = new Person(pid,"person_" + pid );
            pid++;
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println("person = " + person);
        }
    }
}
```

when I clicked the recorded Objects button, it asked me to record allocation to view data. I followed the hint but error occured.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGkzr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40zQh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zajBJ.png)
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your program will not throw a StackOverFlowError just because you profile it with JProfiler. You can check the call frames in the StackOverFlowError message to check why the StackOverFlowError occurs.